# I can't see my app in the list of recently opened Android apps

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

When I pressed home button on my android device, my app should appear on **recent app** but I can't see it.

And this is my manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Libraries_Classes.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Activities.getDataItems"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Activities.FilterActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Activities.AddR"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_r" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Activities.getDataItems" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Activities.RatingAndComment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rating_and_comment" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Activities.FilterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_filter"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Activities.AddL"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_lawyer" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Activities.getDataItems" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Activities.ShowFullImageItem"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_full_image_item" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.hu.restaurantfinalproject.graduationProject.Activities.AddD"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_doctor" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please help!

When I pressed home button on my android device, my app should appear on **recent app** but I can't see it.

Comment: Does your string value `title_activity_filter` contain a value or is it left empty ?

Comment: Ooooh Thanks man ,, no it hasn't value ,, I've entered a value and it works now ... 
thanks again man .

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your `android:label="@string/title_activity_filter"` is defined properly.